# Unable to get media libary items in image field for non-English languages

Tags: sitecore-client

I am facing strange issue with Image field in Sitecore. When I "Browse" image field of any item in English Version then I am able to get entire Media Library with its children but when I change the language of same item  lets say German and try to "Browse" image field then I getting only media library item and not its children, so I am unable to change the image in other language as shown in below image

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do the folders containing your assets have German? It could be that the browse dialogue doesn't show folders which don't exist in your context language.

Comment: What version of Sitecore

Answer (score 2):

I am able to solve this by setting the Source of image field path to "***/sitecore/media library/Images***" in template. Now instead of showing media library as a starting item, my image field showing "Images" as a starting item on Browse functionality and I am able to get its child items as well.

Comment: This is best practice anyway. I would strongly recommend that you have dedicated destination folders for any Image fields to prevent cluttering your Media Library. Ideally they'd be further segregated by site/topic, with the ability to create new items limited to the most taxonomically significant folders within each field's Source folder.